# Trouble sending POST request due to special character in Password

Tags: escaping, apache-httpclient-4.x

So when I make a post request with

```
httpClient.execute(httpPost)
```

I get the following output:

```
09:09:12.181 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "username=qliu&password=213%40vPi" # <==== THIS LINE
    09:09:12.283 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
```

My password is actually `213@vPi` instead of `213%40vPi` But I don't know how to escape the "@" symbol?

```
String password = "213@vPi"; // TODO: how to escape @
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a StringEntity class worked instead.

```
HttpPost prepareLoginHttpPost() {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Configurations.SAND_LOGIN_URL);

        StringEntity authorizationInJSON_Entity = new StringEntity(Configurations.authorizationInJSON);

        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpPost.setEntity(authorizationInJSON_Entity);

        return httpPost;
    }
```